# SQL, Getting start and end date from measuring date in many to many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just to make the situation more clear. I have a table with devices and another with device readings. The table device has devices for each customer. A customer can have had more than 1 device, but only 1 active device. The latest device has EndDate “null” and that is active one. So from table 1 to table 2 is a many to many relation.

Below an example of the table "device":

```
Table1: device

DeviceID      customernr  StartDate   EndDate
1             123         06-05-2002  19-06-2008
2             123         19-06-2008  null
```

I also have another table called device readings. For some reason the only connecting thing is their customer number. Each device can have more than one value.

Below an example of the table "devicereadings":

```
Table2: Devicereadings

customernr   ReadingDate   Value
123          12-05-2002    5
123          20-06-2008    6
123          25-06-2008    7
```

Now I would like to know what the deviceID is for each reading. And to make it more readable for me I would like the start and end date for each reading as well.

I want the following output:

```
Table2: Devicereadings + output i want from table 1

customernr   ReadingDate   Value   DeviceID   StartDate   EndDate
123          12-05-2002    5       1          06-05-2002  19-06-2008
123          20-06-2008    6       2          19-06-2008  null
123          25-06-2008    7       2          19-06-2008  null
```

Below is the query that I used but a lot of the times it returns start and end dates for the wrong reading date. For example reading date in 2019 but the start/end date is like 2002-2003.

```
Select

a.customernr
a.ReadingDate
a.Value
b.DeviceID
b.StartDate
b.EndDate

From Devicereadings a

   LEFT JOIN Device b
   on b.customernr = a.customernr
      WHERE 
         ReadingDate > StartDate and
         ReadingDate < EndDate or
         b.EndDate is null
```

I tried a lot more and different combinations in the where but I honestly don’t know what I’m doing and if I’m looking in the right direction. Would love to hear if someone can give me a clue as to where I should go. If I need to make something more clear please ask away!

If you see any typos in my example code, it’s just an example to give a clear view of what the actual query is.

Below is my actual query:

```
select  

        a.MeteringPoint,
        b.Meternummer,
        a.Measurement,
        a.[Time],
        a.[Value],
        a.[Status],
        b.DatumTijdMutatie,
        b.DatumTijdMutatieEnd

from ge.METERREADINGS a 

    left JOIN ul.Meters b
    on b.AansluitingID = a.MeteringPoint
        WHERE

        REPLACE((CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LEFT([Time],10),105)),'.','-') > CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),b.DatumTijdMutatie,110) and
        REPLACE((CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LEFT([Time],10),105)),'.','-') < CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),b.DatumTijdMutatieEnd,110)or
        b.DatumTijdMutatieEnd is null or

        REPLACE((CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LEFT([Time],10),105)),'.','-') > CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),b.DatumTijdMutatie,110) and
        REPLACE((CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LEFT([Time],10),105)),'.','-') < CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),b.DatumTijdMutatieEnd,110) and 
        b.DatumTijdMutatieEnd is not null or

        REPLACE((CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LEFT([Time],10),105)),'.','-') > CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),b.DatumTijdMutatie,110) and 
        b.DatumTijdMutatieEnd is null
```

Below some translations from my basic query to the actual query above:

- Time =  Meater reading
- DatumTijdMutatie = StartDate
- DatumTijdMutatieEnd = EndDate
- Meternummer = DeviceID
- MeteringPoint = customernr

I also don't know if my query itself is good because of the conversions for dates. The reason for those is because dates get saved as text (which I sadly can’t change). Time, datumtijdmutatie and datumtijdmutatie do however look the same like DD-MM-YYY after the conversion. Before it looks like [image: date text]

If you have any idea please let me know !

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @device table
(
DeviceId int,
customernr int,
StartDate char(10),
EndDate char(10)
);

insert into @device(DeviceId, customernr, StartDate, EndDate)
values
(1, 123, '06-05-2002', '19-06-2008'),
(2, 123, '19-06-2008', null);

declare @Devicereadings table
(
customernr int,
ReadingDate char(10),
value int
);

insert into @Devicereadings(customernr, ReadingDate, value)
values
(123, '12-05-2002', 5),
(123, '20-06-2008', 6),
(123, '25-06-2008', 7);


Select
    a.customernr, a.ReadingDate, a.Value,
    b.DeviceID, b.StartDate, b.EndDate
From @Devicereadings a
LEFT JOIN @Device b on b.customernr = a.customernr 
                    and convert(date, a.ReadingDate, 105) >= convert(date, b.StartDate, 105) 
                    and (convert(date, a.ReadingDate, 105) < convert(date, b.EndDate, 105) or b.EndDate is null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I can't use convert like that because of the way the date is stored, and like this I get lots of double reading dates, because of the “or”. So now I made the logic like ReadingDate > StartDate and readingdate < EndDate or Readingdate > startdate and Enddate is null, which seems to work. I did have to change the way I was using my dates though with some CTE’s. And it works now.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end the problem was that my dates where still wrong because of the way I handled them. I now did this in cte’s for both tables to make sure the dates are all the same formatting and saved as a date. 
Below my new query which seems to work (hard to validate 500k rows) but from what I can see it works like I intend it to work:

```
select 
x.MeteringPoint,
y.Meternummer,
x.MeetDate,
x.[Value],
x.[Status],
y.MeterBeginDatum,
y.MeterEindDatum,
y._meta_ModifiedOn

from cte_meterReadings_stap_final x
left join cte_UL_Meters_stap_final y
on y.AansluitingID = x.MeteringPoint
where 

x.MeetDate => y.MeterBeginDatum and
x.MeetDate =< y.MeterEindDatum or

x.MeetDate => y.MeterBeginDatum and
y.MeterEindDatum is null
```

If you want to see the cte’s, message me, they are a bit of a mess though and I don’t think they would add to this answer.